# Grep used on SSH command output does not return a PIPESTATUS

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Grep doesn't return a pipestatus in the script but does in the shell.

See the included script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function testSshConnection() {
  local SSH_CMD="ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=3 $1@$2 2>&1 | grep \"Host key verification failed.\""
  echo "RUNNING: $SSH_CMD"
  $SSH_CMD
  PIPE_RESULT="${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
  echo "FUNCTION: PIPE_RESULT: ${PIPE_RESULT}"
  PIPE_RESULT_ARRAY=($PIPE_RESULT)
  PIPE0="${PIPE_RESULT_ARRAY[0]}"
  PIPE1="${PIPE_RESULT_ARRAY[1]}"
  local RC=${PIPE1:-$PIPE0}
  echo "Returning RC=$RC"
  return $RC
}

while ! testSshConnection root $1; do
  PIPE_RESULT="${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
  echo "WHILE: PIPE_RESULT: ${PIPE_RESULT}"  
  PIPE_RESULT_ARRAY=($PIPE_RESULT)
  PIPE0="${PIPE_RESULT_ARRAY[0]}"
  PIPE1="${PIPE_RESULT_ARRAY[1]}"
  WAIT=4
  echo "Waiting $SLEEP seconds for host $1 to be accessible on port 22"
  sleep $WAIT
done

exit
```

Script Output:

```
~ $ /tmp/test.sh 46.101.7.220
RUNNING: ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=3 root@46.101.7.220 2>&1 | grep "Host key verification failed."
Host key verification failed.
FUNCTION: PIPE_RESULT: 255
Returning RC=255
WHILE: PIPE_RESULT: 255
 Waiting 4 seconds for host 46.101.7.220 to be accessible on port 22
RUNNING: ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=3 root@46.101.7.220 2>&1 | grep "Host key verification failed."
Host key verification failed.
FUNCTION: PIPE_RESULT: 255
Returning RC=255
WHILE: PIPE_RESULT: 255
...etc
```

Output from running the ssh command in a seperate shell:

```
~ $ ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=3 root@46.101.7.220 2>&1 | grep "Host key verification failed."
Host key verification failed.
~ $ echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
255 0
```

Why does the ssh command in the script not return a ${PIPESTATUS[1]} for the grep command?

Comment: Don't put commands in variables.

Comment: Pipes and redirections aren't processed when expanding variables. You need to use `eval`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether you're doing it in a script or interactively. If you used the variable interactively you'd have the same problem.

Comment: @Barmar Why not?

Comment: Why not what? Cyrus told you not to do something, not me.

Comment: @Barmar When I run the script with bash -x it looks like it is passing the args to the command: +(test.sh:12): testSshConnection(): ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=3 root@46.101.7.220 '2>&1' '|' grep '"Host' key verification 'failed."' - What does this mean exactly: "Pipes and redirections aren't processed when expanding variables"?

Comment: Read my answer, or read the bash manual's section on how it processes a command line and the order of expansions.

Comment: @vy218: `2>&1` and `|` are handled as a normal strings and not as output redirection.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for additinal details, I'm still confused on this though

Comment: I thought you didn't read my answer because you posted the comment here, not below the answer.

Comment: I've added some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `eval` to process `$SSH_CMD` as if it were typed as a command.

```
eval "$SSH_CMD"
```

The only processing that's done after expanding a variable is word splitting and file globbing. It doesn't process ecapes, pipes, redirections, command delimiters, etc. So when you executed that command, it was equivalent to executing:

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=3 root@46.101.7.220 '2>&1' '|' grep '"Host' key verification 'failed."'
```

I've quoted the parts of the command that contain shell metacharacters, to indicate that they're not treated specially after expanding the variable.

The result of this is that the command "2>&1 | grep ...`will be sent to the remote host. This will execute the commands`2>&1`and`grep ...` on the server, not on the client, with the piping being done on the server as well.

For a simpler example, try this:

```
data="foo | wc"
echo $data
```

This will print `foo | wc` literally, it won't execute `echo foo` and then pipe it to `wc`. But if you do:

```
eval "echo $data"
```

it will act as if you'd written

```
echo foo | wc
```

For more details, see the section [Shell Operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Operation.html#Shell-Operation) in the Bash Manual. Processing metacharacters like `|` and `>` is done in this step:

3. Parses the tokens into simple and compound commands (see [Shell Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Commands.html#Shell-Commands)).

Expanding variables is done in the next step:

4. Performs the various shell expansions (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions)), breaking the expanded tokens into lists of filenames (see [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion)) and commands and arguments.

Since variable expansion happens *after* looking for pipes and redirection, those actions won't be done locally, they'll be done on the remote system when the command is sent by `ssh`.

Comment: Your answer dosn't make sense, if you remove the quotes that you added THAT is the command I was running! What do you mean by treated specially? Do they just get treated as if they are args to the command?

Comment: They're treated as ordinary characters, just like letters and numbers.

Comment: That's my point. Because it came from expansion of a variable, the command you're executing is like it would be if you quoted all those tokens, not the command you were trying to execute. That's why I added the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for adding the details, the bit about the 2>&1 | grep running on the server rather than the client is what makes is much clearer.